# How to avoid a line on the top of the header when we use headers in angularjs?

Tags: css, angularjs

Here I have done a heading .Below is the source code.So i am getting a white space on the top of the heading .How to avoid it.Once see it visual in the below fiddle and try to help me to avoid it .And I just want to know the reason why it has been came like that..Thank You.

http://jsfiddle.net/RLQhh/2625/

```
<body ng-controller="controller">
        <div id="header">
            <h1><div id="header_name" style="padding-top:25px"><center><a><B>Dynamic Creation of Registration Form</B></a></center></div><h1></h1>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: The h1 is taking up a margin-top of 20px by default from bootstrap.css. You can override that

Comment: As i have did like below,If i am using any p tag and tried to display anything its displaying size of header.Once check this jsfiddle.net/RLQhh/2631

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See how I have added extra styling to the h1

```
#header h1 { margin-top; 0}
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RLQhh/2628/)

Comment: As i have did like above,If i am using any p tag and tried to display anything its displaying size of header.Once check this http://jsfiddle.net/RLQhh/2631/